# Avoid adding "_1" to field names when reading csv in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, csv

When I read my csv file below

```
"Data Source","World Development Indicators",

"Last Updated Date","2017-02-01",

"Country Name","Country Code","Indicator Name","Indicator Code","1960","1961","1962","1963","1964","1965","1966","1967",...
Actual data...
```

[image]

"_1" is added to "1960","1961",...

Why does it happen and how can I avoid it?

My environment is Ubuntu 14.04 and QGIS 2.18.1

Comment: Neither "1960" nor "1960_1" is a legal SQL identifier (they would need to start with an alpha [a-z]), but "1960_1" is at least a string.

Comment: using column names that start with a number will cause problems later if you try to style the layer using those columns,

Comment: Ok, so it's related to SQL and to make is explicitly string, it automatically add "_1". I don't know much about SQL but it seems like I should change column names before importing to QGIS. Thank you for the comments!